# Remove class in the footer.php file if page is front-page.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following HTML div in the footer:

```
<div class="container mt-5 space-1">
```

What is the easiest way to remove the class `mt-5` if the page is front-page.php? thank you.

Comment: if(url == front) $('div.container').removeClass('mt-5');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="container<?php (is_front_page()) ? "" : " mt-5"; ?> space-1">
```

or

```
<div class="container<?php (is_front_page() && is_home()) ? "" : " mt-5"; ?> space-1">
```

Comment: I actually tried your suggestion in different ways and I could not get it to work. I followed your approach and came out with this working code: `<div class="container<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : echo ' '; else : echo ' mt-5'; endif; ?> space-1">`

Comment: @Foxtrail815 ok great. Glad to help. :) If it helped, can you checked it for correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time and everybody else for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In **javascript** you will get the `url` for `front-page.php` file, and do the following:

```
var url = /* get your front page url */

if(url == 'front-page-url') {
    if($('div.container').hasClass('mt-5')) {
      $('div.container').removeClass('mt-5')
    }
}
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: What is `front-page` suppose to be? A string? A variable?

Comment: It suppose to be a string of your front-page.

Comment: Isn't it easier to use Wordpress's `is_front_page()` function?

Comment: Thanks for your time but I wanted to avoid javascript and actually used the following code which worked `<div class="container<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : echo ' '; else : echo ' mt-5'; endif; ?> space-1">`

Answer (score 0):

**is_front_page()**

Determines whether the query is for the front page of the site.

```
if ( is_front_page() ) :
  ?>
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   if(jQuery('div.container').hasClass('mt-5')) {
      jQuery('div.container').removeClass('mt-5')
    }
});
</script>
  <?php
endif;
```

As per comments of @magnus-eriksson,

> The proper way would be to have the footer in footer.php which you
>   include where it's needed. Either way, if the footer code would exist
>   in several files, only one of them would be loaded on the front page.
>   So you would just need to change that one. Using javascript is
>   definitely not the correct way. Also, this would actually load the
>   page with the class and then remove the class after the page is loaded
>   (which means that you probably would notice the footer changing).

Edit footer.php file add conditional statment :

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
  echo '<div class="container space-1">';
} else {
  echo '<div class="container mt-5 space-1">';
}
```

Useful link:

How to create static frontpage

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

How to manage multiple footer

https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

https://www.webascender.com/blog/create-multiple-headers-footers-wordpress/

Comment: Why don't you just change the div directly, instead of doing it with javascript?

Comment: Yes but this is not clear in question where is div placed.

Comment: Why would that matter?

Comment: You can make changes in each file is not proper way.

Comment: The proper way would be to have the footer in `footer.php` which you include where it's needed. Either way, if the footer code would exist in several files, only one of them would be loaded on the front page. So you would just need to change that one. Using javascript is definitely not the correct way. Also, this would actually load the page with the class and then remove the class after the page is loaded (which means that you probably would notice the footer changing).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I agree with you. what would the difference be if adding the static footer code to `front-page.php` instead of a PHP conditional in the footer in terms of performance if any?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you clarification. I agree with you we can do that way as well.

Comment: @Foxtrail815 There is no difference in case of performance yes this might be easy to manage as well. front-page.php is standalone file.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just have one file for the footer if the only diff is a class. Otherwise, you would need to update multiple files if you want to change something in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

if the page is front-page.php and div tag is written in front-page.php file then we can add below condition in php script to remove the mt-5 class

```
if(basename(__FILE__, '.php') === 'front-page.php') {
  echo '<div class="container space-1">';
} else {
  echo '<div class="container mt-5 space-1">';
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and could not get it to work without modifying it a bit: `<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : echo '<div class="container space-1">'; else : echo '<div class="container mt-5 space-1">'; endif; ?>`